# Phonegap Jquery mobile css not working on windows8 device/emulator

Tags: android, css, cordova, jquery-mobile

I  am developing a mobile application using phonegap v2.7.In the application I use jquery mobile css. The application runs fine on android platform.But whenever I run application on windows8 emulator or device jquery mobile,css does not working.I have used the following code of jquery mobile css in both platform.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-
1.4.2.min.css">
```

Image from Android platform

[image]

Image from windows phone

[image]

Comment: it's probably a whitelist issue, you can whitelist the jquery url, but the best choice here is to download the javascript and css and load it from the www folder, not from internet

Comment: @jcesarmobile  I had copied js and css files on js and css folder which is inside in www floder and using below code.

    <script src="./js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css /jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" />  

Above code working in android device and displaying jquery mobile layout but not displaying jquery mobile layout in windows8 device or emulator.